# PHP preg_replace occurrence of any text after the very last underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I can do this using `explode` (or have fun with with `strrpos`), but i prefer to using `preg_replace` because should be a bit faster, i think (isn't it?). Plus, it's concise and elegant.

The purpose is, given a string like `a_b_c` to obtain another sting **where characters following the last `_`** where substituted with passed string.

I'm not good at regular expression. I've to find the time to buy a good book at study. Anyway i've tried this regex `'/_(.*)$/'` as *match the end of the string, capture any character following the last underscore*.

What's wrong in my argumentation?

```
// Do it using explode
function foo($string, $replacement)
{
    $pieces = explode('_', $string);
    array_pop($pieces);
    return implode('_', array_merge($pieces, array($replacement)));
}

// Do it using regular expression (not working)
function bar($string, $replacement)
{
    return preg_replace('/_(.*)$/', $replacement, $string);
}

echo foo('a_b_c', 3); // Prints a_b_3
echo bar('a_b_c', 3); // Prints a3 wrong!!!
```

Comment: I've got a problem. I want regex! Now I've got two problems ;)

Comment: preg is slower than simple string functions .. in most cases

Comment: @Hajo agreed - and in certain cases, it's much slower, depending on the actual regex used; see my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your common search string and your version of PCRE, either `preg_replace` or `strrpos` will probably fare best:

### Functions

```
function usingExplode($string, $replacement) {
    $pieces = explode('_', $string);
    array_pop($pieces);
    return implode('_', array_merge($pieces, array($replacement)));
}

function usingStrrpos($string, $replacement) {
    return substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '_') + 1) . $replacement;
}

function usingPreg($string, $replacement) {
    return preg_replace('/_[^_]*$/', '_' . $replacement, $string);
}
```

### Test harness

```
function speedTest($function, $string, $count = 100000) {
    $start = microtime(true);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $function($string, 'replacement');
    }

    $end = microtime(true);

    printf('%-12s: %01.2fs%s', $function, $end - $start, PHP_EOL);
}

$tests = array('a_b_c', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy_z', 'a_bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k_l_m_n_o_p_q_r_s_t_u_v_w_x_y_z');

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo $test . ':' . PHP_EOL;
    speedTest('usingExplode', $test);
    speedTest('usingStrrpos', $test);
    speedTest('usingPreg',    $test);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Results

```
a_b_c:
usingExplode: 0.64s
usingStrrpos: 0.34s
usingPreg   : 0.33s

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy_z:
usingExplode: 0.61s
usingStrrpos: 0.32s
usingPreg   : 0.32s

a_bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:
usingExplode: 0.60s
usingStrrpos: 0.32s
usingPreg   : 0.32s

a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k_l_m_n_o_p_q_r_s_t_u_v_w_x_y_z:
usingExplode: 1.39s
usingStrrpos: 0.32s
usingPreg   : 0.71s
```

Note that (at least on my set-up with PHP 5.4.0), `preg_replace` gives `strrpos` a run for its money until there are a large number of underscores preceding the last one.

**EDIT**: I plugged [bfrohs's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236047/283078) into the suite and unless the underscore to replace is near the beginning of the string, it doesn't do very well:

```
a_b_c:
usingPreg2: 0.40s

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy_z:
usingPreg2: 1.91s

a_bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:
usingPreg2: 0.38s

a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k_l_m_n_o_p_q_r_s_t_u_v_w_x_y_z:
usingPreg2: 1.04s
```

Comment: You'll probably get better performance by using `/_[^_]+$/`, which means you also need to do `"_$replacement"`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I included the subpattern in the first place. I re-ran without it and it does improve the performance in the last case (0.5s), but it's still not as quick as `strrpos`. Anyway, I've removed the subpattern.

Answer (score 3):

You were close, the pattern you're looking for is this:

```
([^_]*)$
```

This would match only the text which is not underscore, as close as possible from the end of the string. It would also not include the underscore, as your replacement string does not use `$1` to designate the matching groups.

Comment: That works, but it's not best practice to use non-greedy matching when what you really want is a more restrictive set of matched characters. It's fragile in the face of format changes, and fails to clearly convey the intent. I recommend Friedl's book for discussion of the topic.

Comment: Should i pass any parameter to preg_replace? Seems not working even adding the lazy char.

Comment: @Gremo I have edited my answer, the pattern I gave you (mysteriously) doesn't work, this one will however.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first underscore is matched. You want anything after the underscore **except** an underscore:

```
'/_([^_]*)$/'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expresson `/_(.*)$/` matches an underscore, followed by any text, followed by the end of the string.  There's nothing keeping that "any text" from including underscores, and by default, the matcher will pick the leftmost, longest match.  So in 'a_b_c' it matches right after the 'a'.

You can fix that by replacing the `.` (which matches any character) with the character class `[^_]`, which matches any character *except* an underscore.

Also, since you're not doing anything with the captured group, there's no need for the parentheses.  And since, based on your example, you don't want to replace the underscore itself, you should leave it out of the regular expression.

```
function bar($string, $replacement)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^_]*$/', $replacement, $string, 1);
}
```

Comment: Same problem as Truth solution, `preg_replace('/([^_]*)$/', '3', 'a_b_c')` got `a_b_33`.

Comment: ah, apparently preg_replace defaults to global.  So you need to use [^_]+ or limit=1.  Since @bfrohs updated his answer to do the former, I updated mine to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Using strpos will be faster than preg_replace if speed is your concern. All string functions are (as far as I know) slower than regex functions.

Here's one of the speed tests: http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm

Answer (score 0):

`'/([^_]+)$/'` matches everything *but* an underscore *after* the last underscore.

***Note:** There's no need to match the underscore with this. That way, you don't lose the last underscore when you do the replacement.*

Comment: `preg_replace('/([^_]*)$/', '3', 'a_b_c')` i get `a_b_33`, it doubles the replacement...

Comment: @Gremo, apologies, fixed now. Issue was with not using a `limit` with `preg_replace()`, so it was replacing both `c` and `` (at end of string). So, you can either use the `+` I changed my answer to, or include a limit of `1` in `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an emoticon, but I think it should work:

```
return preg_replace('/(.*_).*/', $replacement, $string);
```